# Boost TR1 include problems in Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

Tags: c++, ubuntu, boost, makefile, klee

I've installed boost version 1.54 on a 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04.1 OS and I'm trying to compile KLEE with metaSMT. However, I think my problem is independent of KLEE and metaSMT, hence the title of the question. Nevertheless, I present the steps needed to reproduce the error.

Prior to this step I have successfully built and ran KLEE with STP. I have successfully built metaSMT according to the instructions [here](http://srg.doc.ic.ac.uk/projects/klee-multisolver/getting-started.html). Afterwards, I configured KLEE with metaSMT and when I execute the `make ENABLED_OPTIMIZED=1` command I get the following error:

```
In file included from /home/user/metaSMT/build/root/include/metaSMT/DirectSolver_Context.hpp:19:0, 
                 from Solver.cpp:54:
/usr/include/boost/tr1/unordered_map.hpp:15:66: fatal error: ../4.8.2/tr1/std::tr1::unoredered_map: No such file or directory
#   include BOOST_TR1_STD_HEADER(BOOST_TR1_PATH(unordered_map))
                                                               ^
compilation terminated.
```

I don't know the absolute path in which the previous `No such file or directory` occurs, but I checked my file system and there is one directory: `/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/tr1` which contains the file `unordered_map`. Additionally, I don't know how to get rid of the `std::tr1::` which is appended to the file name. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: That codepath will never be hit with a normal compiler, which will use the `include_next` on the previous line. Additionally, it looks like there's probably a macro, because BOOST_TR1_PATH just prepends "tr1/" to its argument and BOOST_TR1_STD_HEADER just prepends ../<gcc version>/ and surrounds it with <>.

Comment: @o11c the 2 macros do indeed what you said. And I would suspect that the relative path `../4.8.2/tr1/` from the error message is actually `/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/tr1`. However, my problem is mainly how to get rid of the `std::tr1::` prefix of the file name.